# Luna (0.2.1) sometimes won't load desktop environment after a reboot

Tags: boot, desktop, luna

Quite often, I'll reboot my machine, i.e., after an update or for some other reason. When the machine reboots, elementary OS won't boot with a desktop, but rather just a command prompt. I can log in via the shell and that sort of thing, but there's no desktop environment.

I am using 64bit Luna 0.2.1

Any idea how I can 1) avoid this from happening; or 2) if it does happen, how do I launch the desktop environment from the shell?